# Don't know how to call function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am writing a search function in C which uses pointers and structs. Search is possible by name using an array called `contatcs` with ten entries. The array has already been initialized and populated and works as intended.

I have tried to fix the problem by restructuring my code, but it only made matters worse. Maybe there is some flaw in the design logic that I cannot find.

```
typedef struct
{
    char streetname[150];
    char city[50];
    int zipcode;
}address;

typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int age;
    address homeaddress;
}person;

int search (char* name, person *contacts, int size);

[...] // initialization and population of array omitted

int search (char *name, person *contacts, int size)
{
    int i;
    printf("Input name: ");
    char userin = scanf("%s", name);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(contacts[i].name, &userin) == 0)
        {
            printf("Name: %s;", contacts[i].name);
            printf(" Age: %d;", contacts[i].age);
            printf(" Adress: %s, ", contacts[i].homeaddress.streetname);
            printf("%s, ", contacts[i].homeaddress.city);
            printf("%d\n", contacts[i].homeaddress.zipcode);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am just trying to call the function. But every time I try to do so, it just doesn't work. I know this question is rather basic, but I can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: userin is a char, not a string. strcmp() will most likely fail with &userin as arg

Comment: "Just doesn't work" just isn't informative.  Does your program fail to compile (with what diagnostic)?  Does it fail at runtime (with what specific observable behavior)?

Comment: the program compiles. it just ignores the function call, so I am guessing the call doesn't work. i can't use debug mode, as it isn't supported in CLion with Visual Studio. so I have exactly zero information as to why it won't work. all I can see is that it doesn't.

Comment: why the _name_ given in argument is not the one you want to search on ? initialize _name_ out of _search_ seems more logical. Note also _search_ always returns 0, it must return the index in the array of contact, else for instance -1 no ?

Comment: Bjorn A. thank you. but as there are no error messages, I guess that something else must be the problem regarding why the function call is completely ignored. but I will use your input and try to fix the problem with strcmp()'s argument.

Comment: If the program in fact does not call the function, then the problem is in the code you have omitted, where the call appears.  Please present a [mcve] that reproduces the issue, not merely a selection of excerpts that you think relevant.

Comment: bruno return 0 is needed to know if everything went as expected. it doesn't return 0 alone, if it works as supposed, it should print out the entry and then return 0, so that I know everything worked out. as for `name` I am trying to access array `contacts` where all the information from the struct are saved. so I should be able to type in "Arnold" and find the contact.name which is "Arnold" and then print out the rest of Arnold's information.

Comment: @MichaelPrammer, I believe bruno's point is that your search function, as presented, never returns any value other than zero, so its return value does not convey any actionable information to the caller.  In particular, it does not tell you whether *anything* worked out, because 0 is returned either way.  If indeed you do not intend ever to return a different value, then it would be cleaner to declare the function to return nothing (`void`), and to not return any value at all.

Comment: The "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable" essence is that I don't know what I am doing wrong. I thought I kinda understood C but it seems that I don't. No matter where I put the function call - which, by the way, looks something like ´search();´ with params for name, contacts, and size, - it is just ignored. As is probably the rest of the search function which seems to be full of holes too. So maybe it's a scope thing. But I'll dig into that myself, as the only thing I can count on here seems to be snide remarks and downvotes.

Comment: First solve the problem with `char userin` and then update the question. It's vital to the function, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char userin = scanf("%s", name);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(contacts[i].name, &userin) == 0)
```

You can not use `strcmp` with a `char`, `userin` must be a NUL terminated array of `char`s

And as pointed out by @JohnBollinger in comments, it seems you want to compare the `name`, not the result of `scanf`

Comment: Moreover, `userin` seems unlikely to be what the OP wants to compare to in the first place.  It seems likely that they actually want `strcmp(contacts[i].name, name)`.

Comment: ok. it seems that my search function is crap. that doesn't surprise me though as I am a programming novice at best. but CLion doesn't complain and just compiles. so probably the scope is broken and that's why my function call is lost to the void too. so I'll just check this as the answer and we can all focus on something else.